# Pegar miniatura dos vídeos (Windows)

Tags: java

Procurei no Google por vários termos de como pegar a thumbnail dos vídeos mas só encontrei como "gerar" a *thumbnail* de um *frame* do vídeo usando o `Xuggler`, mas estou tendo erros.

O erro que estou tendo é:
[image: Imagem com o erro]

Segue abaixo minha classe:

```
package util;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaListenerAdapter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.event.IVideoPictureEvent;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Global;

import model.Video;

public class BuildThumbnailUtil {

    public static final double SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 1;
    private static final String outputFilePrefix = "C:/Documents and Settings/Panda/Desktop/MovieList/";
    private static int mVideoStreamIndex = -1;
    private static long mLastPtsWrite = Global.NO_PTS;
    public static final long MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = (long) (Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND * SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES);

    public static void buildThumbnail(List<Video> videos) {
        for (Video v : videos) {
            IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(v.getPath());
            try {
                mediaReader.setBufferedImageTypeToGenerate(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
                ImageSnapListener isListener = new ImageSnapListener();
                mediaReader.addListener(isListener);

                while (!isListener.isImageGrabbed()) {
                    mediaReader.readPacket();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class ImageSnapListener extends MediaListenerAdapter {

        public boolean imageGrabbed = false;

        public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event) {
            if (event.getStreamIndex() != mVideoStreamIndex) {
                if (mVideoStreamIndex == -1)
                    mVideoStreamIndex = event.getStreamIndex();
                else
                    return;
            }
            if (mLastPtsWrite == Global.NO_PTS)
                mLastPtsWrite = event.getTimeStamp() - MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;
            if (event.getTimeStamp() - mLastPtsWrite >= MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES * 10) {
                String outputFilename = dumpImageToFile(event.getImage());
                this.imageGrabbed = true;
                double seconds = ((double) event.getTimeStamp()) / Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND;
                System.out.printf("at elapsed time of %6.3f seconds wrote: %s\n", seconds, outputFilename);
                mLastPtsWrite += MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;
            }
        }

        private String dumpImageToFile(BufferedImage image) {
            try {
                String outputFilename = outputFilePrefix + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                System.out.println("Thumbnail image name is going to be : =====>" + outputFilename);
                ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(outputFilename));
                return outputFilename;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        public boolean isImageGrabbed() {
            return imageGrabbed;
        }
    }
}
```

Alguém sabe se tem uma forma de pegar a mesma thumbnail de um vídeo, assim como o Windows exibe?

Comment: Pandemonio, você poderia colar a mensagem de erro em formato textual (imagens são difíceis de ver e dificultam a vida de quem vai responder).

Answer (score 1):

Como respondi no outro tópico seu, segue outra classe que também funciona aqui perfeitamente!

```
package xug;


import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaListenerAdapter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.event.IVideoPictureEvent;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Global;

public class Main {

    public static final double SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES = 10;
    private static final String inputFilename = "D:\\pasta de videos\\Live for free.flv";
    private static final String outputFilePrefix = "D:\\imaagens\\";

    private static int mVideoStreamIndex = -1;
    private static long mLastPtsWrite = Global.NO_PTS;
    public static final long MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES =
            (long) (Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND * SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(inputFilename);
        mediaReader.setBufferedImageTypeToGenerate(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        mediaReader.addListener(new ImageSnapListener());
        while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null);

    }

    private static class ImageSnapListener extends MediaListenerAdapter {
         public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event) {

            if (event.getStreamIndex() != mVideoStreamIndex) {

                if (mVideoStreamIndex == -1) {
                    mVideoStreamIndex = event.getStreamIndex();
                }
                else {
                    return;
                }
            }


            if (mLastPtsWrite == Global.NO_PTS) {
                mLastPtsWrite = event.getTimeStamp() - MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;
            }

            if (event.getTimeStamp() - mLastPtsWrite
                    >= MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES) {

                String outputFilename = dumpImageToFile(event.getImage());

                double seconds = ((double) event.getTimeStamp())
                        / Global.DEFAULT_PTS_PER_SECOND;

                System.out.printf(
                        "at elapsed time of %6.3f seconds wrote: %s\n",
                        seconds, outputFilename);

                mLastPtsWrite += MICRO_SECONDS_BETWEEN_FRAMES;

            }
        }

        private String dumpImageToFile(BufferedImage image) {

            try {

                String outputFilename = outputFilePrefix
                        + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";

                ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(outputFilename));

                return outputFilename;

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                return null;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

É bem semelhante a essa sua, o mais engraçado é que pegando sua classe passei a ter esse erro seu... Vou dar uma depurada e ver se acho a maior diferença!

Answer (score 0):

Parece haver alguns exemplos lá fora, que são muito melhores do que o que eu estava indo para enviar-lhe.

Veja http://krishnabhargav.blogspot.com/2008/02/processing-videos-in-java.html.

Se você puder encontrar uma maneira de obter o que deseja usar algumas ferramentas de linha de comando (e executá-los usando Commons-Exec), você pode ter uma solução global melhor do que dependendo do que é essencialmente o sânscrito de extensões Java.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179/video-thumbnails-in-java